# no se actualiza correctamente mi estado en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

Tengo un problema en mi formulario y es que el estado del mismo no se actualiza correctamente, se actualiza al escribir un caracter mas del input, por ejemplo:

Tengo una función que valida que el usuario tenga números y letras:

> usuario: 123456789a ---> no funciona

> usuario: 12345678ab ---> si funciona

Al poner eso me sale mal la validación, pero al agregarle cualquier numero o letra mas si funciona (es como si tuviera 1 caracter de delay). Les proporciono el código y capturas del mismo

funcion `includesNumbers`

```javascript
const letters = "abcdefghyjklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"

const includesLetters = (text) => {
  text = text.toLowerCase()
    for(let i=0; i<text.length; i++){
       if (letters.indexOf(text.charAt(i), 0) !== -1){
          return 1;
       }
    }
    return 0;
}

export default includesLetters
```

función `includesLetters`

```javascript
const numbers = "0123456789"

const includesNumbers = (text) => {
    for(let i=0; i<text.length; i++){
       if (numbers.indexOf(text.charAt(i), 0) !== -1){
          return 1;
       }
    }
    return 0;
}

export default includesNumbers
```

Código donde declaro el reducer:

```javascript
CODIGO donde declaro el reducer:
const ACTIONSOFERRORS = {
  UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR: "update_account_error",
  UPDATE_PASSWORD_ERROR: "update_password_error",
  UPDATE_COUNTRY_ERROR: "update_country_error",
  UPDATE_PHONE_ERROR: "update_phone_error",
  UPDATE_NAME_ERROR: "update_name_error",
  UPDATE_LASTNAME_ERROR: "update_lastname_error",
  UPDATE_EMAIL_ERROR: "update_email_error",
  UPDATE_CHECKBOX_ERROR: "update_checkbox_error",
  RESET_ERRORS: "reset_errors",
};

const initialStateErrors = {
  accountError: [false, ""],
  passwordError: [false, ""],
  countryError: [false, ""],
  phoneError: [false, ""],
  nameError: [false, ""],
  lastNameError: [false, ""],
  emailError: [false, ""],
  submit: [false],
};


const reducerErrors = (stateErrors, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR:
      return {
        ...stateErrors,
        accountError: action.payload,
      };

    case ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_PASSWORD_ERROR:
      return {
        ...stateErrors,
        passwordError: action.payload,
      };

    case ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_COUNTRY_ERROR:
      return {
        ...stateErrors,
        countryError: action.payload,
      };

    case ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_EMAIL_ERROR:
      return {
        ...stateErrors,
        emailError: action.payload,
      };

    case ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_LASTNAME_ERROR:
      return {
        ...stateErrors,
        lastNameError: action.payload,
      };

    case ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_PHONE_ERROR:
      return {
        ...stateErrors,
        phoneError: action.payload,
      };

    case ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_CHECKBOX_ERROR:
      return {
        ...stateErrors,
        check: action.payload,
      };

    case ACTIONSOFERRORS.RESET_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...stateErrors,
        stateErrors: initialStateErrors,
      };

    default:
      return stateErrors;
  }
};
const [stateErrors, dispatchErrors] = useReducer(
    reducerErrors,
    initialStateErrors
);
```

Código donde realizo las verificaciones:

```
    <TextField
        variant="outlined"
        label="Account"
        name="user"
        id="user"
        // value={account}
        // error={error}
        value={account}
        error={accountError[0]}
        helperText={accountError[1]}
        onChange={(evt) => {
          const { value } = evt.target;
          dispatch({
            type: ACTIONS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT,
            payload: value,
          });

          account.includes(" ")
            ? dispatchErrors({
                type: ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
                payload: [true, "Username not accept spacing"],
              })
            : account.length < 8
            ? dispatchErrors({
                type: ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
                payload: [true, "Username requerid more of 8 digits"],
              })
            : !(includesNumbers(account) && includesLetters(account))
            ? dispatchErrors({
                type: ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
                payload: [true, "User is required letters and numbers"],
              })
            : dispatchErrors({
                type: ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
                payload: [false, ""],
              });
        }}
      />
```

IMAGEN 1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

IMAGEN 2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]